# ZendServer Expired licence in Openshift

Tags: openshift, zend-server

When I have installed a Zend-Server in a Openshift gear, I have notice that indicates me the Zend Server Licence will expire in 7 days. Is this managed by Openshift or I have to buy a licence after 7 days?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from [Zend Server 6.1 and PHP 5.4 Cloud Hosting](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/zend-server-61-and-php-54-cloud-hosting) OpenShift blog:

> ## License Edition
>
> 1. #### Enterprise Edition license
>
>    Zend Server 6.1 cartridge comes with 7-days free Enterprise Trial
>    license when instantiated. Users can extend the Enterprise Trial
>    license for another 21 days by registering the Zend Server instance or
>    switch to their already purchased license.
> 2. #### Free Edition license
>
>    Once the Enterprise Trial license expires and Zend Server process gets
>    restarted, the application code continues to run with Zend Server now
>    running in [Free Edition](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/free-edition). This edition is still perfectly suited for
>    development environments but lacks features designed for production
>    environments, such as extended data retention, Page Caching, Job
>    Queue, and auto-generated root cause analysis.
>
>    See this comparison of [Zend Server Editions](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/editions) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

According to this page: http://www.zend.com/products/server/license/product?edition=FREE

**

> Sorry, Zend Server Free Edition is no longer available.

**

Be aware that, unless you are a RedHat employee working on this problem, you cannot see any of the details for any of these bug reports, so there is no way to know if there has been any progress - from the Zend Forums, it looks like [this has been a problem for years](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=108483) and has never been fixed.

[Bug 1120132](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1120132) - There is no way to acquire a new Zend Server 6 license when the Enterprise Trial expired

[Bug 1120103](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1120103) - Failed to redirect to the login page or update license page after cancelled the update license on the first time when the Enterprise Trial license expired

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1120132

So, an answer to this question seems impossible to obtain from those responsible for perpetrating it. It looks to be impossible to migrate from the trial licence to the free edition.  This could be down to a design fault in the Zend ecosystem - it might never work and there seems to be no recourse for the user hit by this.

According to [this page](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio-10/zend-studio.htm#uninstalling_zend_studio_on_linux.htm), to uninstall Zend Server, you make sure it's not running and simply delete it.

Comment: More than a year later, this is still an issue. I began with Zend Server, and the trial ran out. When I read what happened after the trial, as @Vojtech said, I thought I could continue to use the free edition. It is partially true, as the free server continues to run, but as DevLondon mentions, free edition is no longer available. So I can't login to server administration. This should really be clarified on the cartridge page so that people can select the PHP cartridge instead. This really leaves users in a bind.

Answer (score 1):

This is something we're aware of and are working on a fix, take a look at this BZ for more information https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1120132.

Comment: I would like to research this issue more, but all the bugzilla links in this post are restricted. Are there other resources I can use?